# How to create a macro to merge splited rows at columns

Tags: excel, merge, rows

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of data in 3 columns:

A: invoice number which is splited to two rows Pay-Receive

B: Definition

C: amount

I need to merge two rows to columns just like the sample below.

Could you help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply drag these down to filer the two out. This should be a good start for what you're looking for...

"Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Looks like StackOverflow will not let me post the images. I have run into this error before.

Since I can not post images it will be hard to explain what I did. You can create a "pay" and "received" column and drag the below formulas down.

```
=IF(B3="pay",C3,"")

=IF(B3="receive",C3,"")
```

Comment: Hi Matthew, if the system does not allow you ti import code, just upload a screenshot of your code. No worries.

Comment: @tasoik No, users should not upload screenshots of code. That is also the _opposite_ of what Matthaeus is trying to do here; they actually did the right thing by posting their code as text rather than trying to do it as an image.